# Assemblies issues error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have getting such error

> Error 112 The type or namespace name 'Repatriation_BO' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is solution for this ?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections; 
using System.Data; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using BusinessObject.BusinessObject;
using BusinessLayer.BusinessLayer; 
using System.Text; using System.Reflection; 
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; 
using ParameterPasser; using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Web.Security; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts; 
using System.DirectoryServices; 
using System.Net.Mail; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Globalization; 
using System.Configuration;  

public partial class ISE_Repatriation : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

   GlobalFunctions gb = new GlobalFunctions();
   Common cs = new Common();    
   CommonBAL cbal = new CommonBAL();     
   public string Urlpage_name;     string lenght_Url;     
   Repatriation_BO repatbo = new Repatriation_BO();     
   Repatriation_BL repatbl = new Repatriation_BL();     
   ISE_Search_BL objISESearch = new ISE_Search_BL();     
   ISEHelper objISE = new ISEHelper();     
   SqlDataReader sdr;
```

Comment: did you reference the assembly for `Repatriation_BO`?

Comment: How can i reference the assembly for Repatriation_BO? Please help me

Comment: go to solution, right click on project -> references -> Add New Reference -> add the dll of the specific project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot instantiate the object `Repatriation_BO`, because it has no knowledge of it, what you need to do is to add this reference to your project.
For what I see `Repatriation_BO` seems to be a third party component or another project, try looking for a similar name in your local directory.

Here you have the steps to add a reference in Visual Studio:

[How to: Add a project reference in VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer.

Comment: if you consider it helpful please mark it as the answer